# MySQL query makes server crash?

Tags: mysql, sql, relation

In my MySQL database I have two tables: 'orders' and 'orders_lines'. Orders contains info about the customer, order date, and so on. Orders_lines contains data about the oredered products, like product_id, price, quantity, tax rate, and so on.

I'm currently building a search-page in which I'd like to return the orders that contain a specific product. For example, I'd like to return all orders with product_id 2. I thought of a query like:

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id IN ( SELECT order_id FROM orders_lines WHERE product_id = 2 )`

But when I executed the query this morning I had to call the hosting provider to terminate the MySQL processes because it was way to heavy. Never heard of it and could not figure out why, and I'm pretty desperate at the moment. The orders table contains about 30.000 rows, the orders_lines table about 38.000 rows.

Any suggestions why my database crashes, how to change the query to make it work correctly or how to achieve my goal of displaying orders that contain a certain product are welcome!

Kind regards,

Martijn

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables? Can you post the tables' definitions?

Comment: Ans is, by any chance, the `order_lines.order_id` NULLable?

Comment: but how can a query put down a mysql server by its own? making all other queries / connections slow too? Why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you need, anyway try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.* FROM orders o
INNER JOIN order_lines ol
ON o.order_id = ol.order_id
WHERE ol.product_id = 2
```

Comment: You are missing a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Daniel: I think that in order_lines you can't have more than one row with product_id = 2... there should be a quantity column... Am I wrong? Anyway, thanks for your suggestion !!!

Comment: That's an assumption that may be correct or may not be. If there are multiple order_lines per order with the same product, the corresponding order will be returned multiple times if the distinct is missing.

Comment: @Daniel: yes, you're right, but in my mind that's not a properly managed order ;) I edit my post anyway, your suggestion is correct. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Since you were the first, I've accepted this answer. The real situation was slightly different, I've abstracted the problem in my starting post. I wasn't searching on the product_id but on a separate field which contains the ordered code. But in the end, the given answer works perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Martijn Dwars: to be honest the first answer (for some second) was the one from @Peter. I was the first to talk about `DISTINCT` with @Daniel. Anyway, I'm glad my post was useful to solve your problem.

Comment: I wonder why this kind of thing can't be optimized by the database.  Seems like something that a lot of people fall into.  Basically, just about any in statement with a sub-select should just run the equivalent join code.  Basically, any query Select * FROM A where A.ID IN (Select ID FROM x WHERE ..) Can be rewritten as SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM X WHERE ...) AS InStatement ON A.ID =InStatment.ID.  This should be something that is simple for the database engine to optimize away without any intervention from the user.

Answer (score 2):

The query can be rewritten with `JOIN` (and `GROUP BY`):

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders o
  INNER JOIN order_lines ol
    ON o.order_id = ol.order_id
WHERE ol.product_id = 2
GROUP BY o.order_id
```

or preferably - as you want only results from the `orders` table - with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders AS o
WHERE EXISTS  
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM orders_lines AS ol
        WHERE ol.product_id = 2 
          AND ol.order_id = o.order_id
      )
```

But check your indexes and the `EXPLAIN` before running again something that might cause your server to fault.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know is an inner join (aka naturual join) the best way to go in such cases.  'WHERE .. IN .. tends to be an expensive operation.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.* FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orders_lines ol ON  o.order_id = ol.order_id 
WHERE ol.product_id = 2
```

Comment: Similar answer is fine... but exactly the same at the same time!! Do you want me to delete mine? :)

Comment: You are missing a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Marco, no never mind, yours is more usefull at this time apparantly :)